# How to return a promise with alertcontroller in ionic 4?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, promise, ionic4

I am trying to convert this ionic 3 code into ionic 4 but I don't know how the promise works on ionic 4. I tried looking into the documentations and I can't find any solutions to promises

```
async generateAlert(header, message, ok, notOk): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let alert = await this.alertController.create({
            header: header,
            message: message,
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: notOk,
                    handler: _=> reject(false)
                },
                {
                    text: ok,
                    handler: _=> resolve(true)
                }
            ]
        })
        await alert.present();
    });
}
```

Comment: Please, can you tell what you want to do ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you can see **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)**:

> The await operator is used to **wait** for a Promise.

So `await` is just another way to work with promises like you can see in the following example:

```
// Method that returns a promise
private resolveAfter2Seconds(x: number): Promise<number> { 
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(x);
    }, 2000);
  });
}

// Using await
private async f1(): Promise<void> {
  var x = await resolveAfter2Seconds(10);
  console.log(x); // 10
}

// Not using await
private f2(): void {
  resolveAfter2Seconds(10).then(x => {
    console.log(x); // 10
  });
}
```

In `f1(){...}` you can see how the app will wait for the promise to be resolved before executing the next line of code. That's why you can do something like

```
var x = await resolveAfter2Seconds(10);
console.log(x); // 10
```

without putting that `console.log(x)` in a `.then(() => {...})` block.

In `f2()` since we don't use `await`, the app won't wait for the promise to be resolved before executing the next line of code, so we must use `then` to print the result in the console:

```
resolveAfter2Seconds(10).then(x => {
  console.log(x); // 10
});
```

---

That being said, if you just want to create a method that shows an alert and returns true/false when the user selects the `ok`/`notOk` buttons, you can do the following (which doesn't use `await` at all):

```
private generateAlert(header: string, message: string, ok: string, notOk: string): Promise<boolean> {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    // alertController.create(...) returns a promise!
    this.alertController
      .create({
        header: header,
        message: message,
        buttons: [
          {
            text: notOk,
            handler: () => resolve(false);
          },
          {
            text: ok,
            handler: () => resolve(true);
          }
        ]
      })
      .then(alert => {
        // Now we just need to present the alert
        alert.present();
      });
  });
}
```

Then you can use that method like this

```
private doSomething(): void {

  // ...

  this.generateAlert('Hello', 'Lorem ipsum', 'Ok', 'Cancel').then(selectedOk => {
    console.log(selectedOk);
  });

}
```